# В Opere глючит верстка при прокрутке

Tags: opera, html, вёрстка, дизайн

У меня есть форум на IPB, хочу купить к нему дополнительный скин "Executive". Вот здесь можно посомтреть данный скин в работе: http://www.finalprestige.net/skinning/? Слева внизу выбрать Change Theme и выбрать Executive 2.
Но проблема в том, что в Opere при прокрутке вниз страницы тормозит верстка. Наблюдается на разных компьютерах. В хроме и ФФ все нормально. И при чем только на этом скине. Теперь вот в сомнениях ставить или нет.
Подскажите из-за чего это происходит в опере? Из-за каких то конкретных элементов HTML, JS или из-за общей загруженности страницы?

Comment: Я бы вам изначально не советовал брать этот шаблон, т.к. он еще явно на этапе альфа-тестирования. По крайней мере именно сама верстка (стилистика) оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: А откуда информация, что он на этапе альфа-тестирования?

Comment: Верстка тормозит, потому что используется много теней и др эффектов.

Comment: Действительно, просто перегруженный шаблон:
![](http://i.imgur.com/KvsGM.png)